# A few errors - trying to convert Roman entry to Decimal

Tags: c++

Just going to change my question for now - I could just use some guidance as to why I have three compiler errors in my program, not quite sure what I did wrong/am missing - I have added comments into the code just to state where they are. Thanks

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>


using namespace std;

class romanType
{

public:
    void setRomanNum(string store);
    // this function will store the Roman numeral

    int convertNum(char rNum);
    // this function will convert the Roman numeral to a decimal

    void decimalPrint(int total);
    // this function will print the decimal number

    void romanPrint(char rNum);
    // this function will print the Roman numeral

    int getNum(char letter);
    // this function will get the number input

    romanType(int store);
    //Constructor with parameter

    romanType();

    char roman[7];
    string num;
    int length = 0;
    string dNum;
    int equals;

};

romanType::romanType(int store)
{
    dNum = 1;

}


void romanType::setRomanNum (string store)
{
    dNum = store;
}

void romanType::romanPrint(char rNum)
{
    cout << "The Roman numeral is: " << roman << endl;
}


void romanType::decimalPrint(int total)
{
    cout << "The Decimal number is: " << equals << endl;
}


int romanType::convertNum (char rNum)
{

    int letter;
    int totalNum = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i< dNum.length(); i++)
        // "loop will run at most once (loop increment never executed)"?

    {

        switch (roman[i])
        {
            case 'M':
                totalNum+= 1000;
                break;

            case 'D':
                totalNum += 500;
                break;

            case 'C':
                totalNum += 100;
                break;

            case 'L':
                totalNum += 50;
                break;

            case 'X':
                totalNum += 10;
                break;

            case 'V':
                totalNum += 5;
                break;

            case 'I':
                totalNum += 1;
                break;

        }
        totalNum = totalNum + letter;
        equals = totalNum;

        return equals;
    }
};
// "control may reach end of non-void function"


int main()
{
    romanType output;


    int rNumeral;
    char entry;


    cout << "Please enter a Roman numeral (Capitalized only): " << endl;
    cin >> rNumeral;

    cout << "Print Decimal or Roman Numeral? Type 1 for Decimal, 2 for Roman Numeral: " << endl;
    cin >> entry;

    if (entry == '1')
    {
        cout << "You chose to view the decimal conversion." << endl;
    output.decimalPrint(rNum);
    // How do I output the decimal conversion from the void romanType::decimalPrint(int total) function?
    }
    else if (entry == '2')
    {


        cout << "You chose to view the Roman numeral." << endl;
    output.romanPrint(rNumeral);
    }
    else
        cout << "Error: bad input" << endl;
    return 0;
        exit(1);


}
```

Comment: Fix the compiler errors 1st, learn how to read them. After you have running code step through with a debugger to catchup with the logical errors. You can't expect us to do that for you here.

Comment: Just fixed a few of the compiler errors, I was unsure how to fix them - still have a couple in there though. If someone could help me with the compiler errors that would be great. I put in a couple comments where I'm getting the errors and don't understand why. I can ask about the logic in a separate question - just thought that was not allowed. Sorry.

Comment: You don't need 3 return statements, you need a default case in the switch stamement. Look it up.

Comment: Your main mistake is that the Roman system is non-positional. You can't just add up consequent Roman digits to get the correct result. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals and en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_notation

Comment: That was my bad - I was getting an error and was messing about and forgot to fix it - I've fixed that now.

Comment: @iksemyonov thank you for the link - that's my main problem, I realize I need to somehow subtract per each numeral that is looped through but am unsure how to do that, hence the logic issue :(

Comment: Yes unfortunately that's something you have to work on yourself and only come back here when you've identified and narrowed down a specific problem, not just 'it doesn't work as expected". That's how Stack Overflow works!

Comment: There are only 2 errors right now and both are discussed in my answer. Please look closer. Also reformat the code; it is *unacceptable* to treat your code like that let alone present it to the public unformatted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The mistake in the algorithm is that the Roman system is non-positional. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals and en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_notation. You can't just add up consequent digits (i.e. letters) but you also have to identify and account for the cases when subtraction takes place.*

> why am I getting the error "no matching constructor for initialization of "roman type"?

Because the only provided constructor is not the default one, but takes one parameter of type `int`. Since such a constructor was provided, the  default constructor wasn't generated by the compiler. Define `romanType::romanType()` or change the existing one to `romanType::romanType(int i = 0)` (add a default parameter). See [Is there an implicit default constructor in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563221/is-there-an-implicit-default-constructor-in-c) and [why default constructor is not available by default in some case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163489/why-default-constructor-is-not-available-by-default-in-some-case)

> expected expression?

Provide braces around the preceding `else` block. More than one statement -> braces required.

```
if (entry == '1') {
    cout << "You chose to view the decimal conversion." << endl;
    output.decimalPrint(rNum);
} else if (entry == '2') 
    cout << "You chose to view the Roman numeral." << endl;
    output.romanPrint(rNumeral);
}
```

> "control may reach end of non-void function"

This is a warning only, but it will turn into an error if you include the `-Werror` flag that tells the compiler to treat all warnings as errors.

Ok I was wrong on this one. Actually the trick is that it is (in theory) possible that the `romanType::convertNum(int)` function follows a route where the `for` loop will never get executed and thus no `return` statement will be executed either. That's bad since the function is declared to return `int` hence there must be present an explicit `return` statement that (surprise) would return a value. Move the `return` out of the loop. This error is also closely related to the next one, discussed below.

> "loop will run at most once (loop increment never executed)"?

This is because the `return` statement is placed incorrectly: inside the `for` loop not outside of it, and inside the function body. Hence the loop runs once and the function returns. Move the return statement. Credit to @**ATN_LR_boom** for noticing this!

Also, please get in the habit of formatting code properly. It will save you a lot of headache down the way.

Other than that, I'd use a `std::map` for the conversion function, it's shorter and more clear to the reader compared to the `switch` statement. Something along the lines of

```
int romanType::convertNum(int rNum) {
    const static std::map<char, int> conversion = {
        {'M', 1000},
        {'D', 500},
        // more mappings
        {'I', 1}
    };
    if ((auto it = conversion.find(rNum)) != conversion.end())
        return it->second;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: AHHHH!!! DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR THANK YOU. Just what I was needing. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic for the switch is wrong, try something like this:

```
int totalNum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i< dNum.length(); i++)
// the loop ran once because you were returning values when catching a letter
{
    switch (roman[i])
    {
        case 'M': // roman[i] is a char, the cases should try to catch chars
            totalNum += 1000; // increment your global number
            break;

        case 'D':
             totalNum += 500;
            break;
        ...
    }
return totalNum;
```